# FFmpeg record rtsp stream to file error

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, record, rtsp

I use ffmpeg to record rtsp stream, it work good but the output file got some proble, when I use use K-Lite Codec Pack to open the output (avi) file the video cant be seek, forward, backward and dont display video time. It lock like i am viewing streaming.

here is the command i used

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://27.74.xxx.xxx:55/ufirststream -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.avi
```

[video playing error with K-Lite Codec Park image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jWxw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like header file not been updated on output file. It's recommended to close output file by pressing "q" button while ffmpeg reads input stream to properly finalize output file.